# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) KeyError: ["Data Bytes 1: "]

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, base64

I have two errors which I cannot figure out how to fix.

First is:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

Second is:

> KeyError["Data Bytes 1: "]

```
def save_details():

global details

with open("customerDetails.json", "wb+") as customer_details: #open customerDetails.json 

        details = { 
            "Data Bytes 1: ": username, 
            "Data Bytes 2: ": user_phone_number, 
            "Data Bytes 3: ": user_password 
        }

        customer_details.write(base64.b64encode(json.dumps(details).encode()))

with open("customerDetails.json", "rb") as customer_details: 
        details = json.loads(base64.b64decode(customer_details.read()).decode())
```

---

```
customers = json.loads(base64.b64decode(open("customerDetails.json", "rb").read()))


if username == customers["Data Bytes 1: "] and user_password == customers["Data Bytes 3: "]:
         print("\nLogin in Successful! ")

else:
      print("\nThere is trouble logging in, please try again.\n ")
      cancel_order() '''
```

Here is the part of my code which is **associated with this problem**.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Seems to be related to the fact you are using bytes when opening your file for reading and writing. Please try ```"wb+"``` instead of "w+" and ```r``` instead of ```rb```.

Comment: wb+ is already written. I tried using 'r' instead of 'rb' and still got the following error: raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Sorry obliviously I meant  ```"w+"``` instead of ```"wb+"``` and ```r``` instead of ```rb```. ```b``` stands for bytes, the problem seems to be related to them. If it doesn't work I would debug what json tries to decode by putting it into ```type()```. You need JSON serializable string in order to parse it successfully.

Comment: Could you please put that into an example for me?

Comment: '''      details = str({ 
                
                "Data Bytes 1: ": username, 
                "Data Bytes 3: ": user_password 
            })
                                                                                 
    details = json.loads(str(base64.b64decode(open("customerDetails.json", "r").read())))

    
    if username == details["Data Bytes 1: "] and user_password == details["Data Bytes 3: "]:
             print("\nLogin in Successful! ")

    else:
          print("\nThere is trouble logging in, please try again.\n ")
          cancel_order()  '''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  with open("customerDetails.json", "rb") as customer_details:
       details = json.loads(base64.b64decode(customer_details.read()).decode())                                                 
  if username == details["Data Bytes 1: "] and user_password == details["Data Bytes 3: "]:
      print("\nLogin Successful! ")
```

Comment: The error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) means that there is no data in the JSON file that you are reading from.  That was my mistake.  Next, it fix the key error, you need to firstly open the JSON file as 'read bytes' then decode it using json.loads and b64.decode and then it should work.